# How to specify value of theano.tensor.ivector?

Tags: theano, tensor

I would like to create a `theano.tensor.ivector` variable and specify its values. In most code examples on the internet, I find `v = T.ivector()`. This creates the tensor variable but don't specify its value. 
I tried this :

```
import theano.tensor as T
val = [1,5]
v = T.ivector(value=val, name='v')
```

but I get the following error :

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'value'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be a little confused about the use of tensors, as it isn't a traditional variable that you assign a value to on declaration.  A tensor is really a placeholder variable with a specified format that you will use in a function later.  Extending on your example:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function
val = [1, 5]
v = T.ivector('v')
f = function([v], [v]) # Create a function that just returns the input
# Evaluate the function
f(val)
```

In the above code we just create a function that takes the tensor v and returns it.  The value is not assigned until we call the function **f(val)**

You may find the [baby steps](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/adding.html) page of the documentation helpful